Solving PDE with Fourier Transformation
Solve the following PDE:
\begin{align*}u_{tt} + u_{xx} &=0,\quad -\infty<x<\infty,t>0\\ u(x,0) &= \left \{\begin{array}{rr}1, & -1\le x\le 1\\ 0, &\text{otherwise}\end{array}\right . \\ u_t(x,0)=0,&\quad u,u_x\to 0 \;\text{for}\;|x|\to \infty. \end{align*}

My Attempt
Note that $0 = \hat{u}_{tt} -k^2 \hat{u} \implies \hat{u}(k,t)=C_1(k)e^{kt}+C_2(k)e^{-kt}$. I have found that for $f(x) = \chi_{[-a,a]}= \left \{\begin{array}{rr}1, &-a\le x\le a\\ 0, &\text{otherwise} \end{array}\right .$ for $a>0$ implies $\hat{f}(k)= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{\sin (ka)}{k}$. We have
$$0= \hat{u}_t(k,0)=kC_1(k)-kC_2(k)\implies C_1(k)=C_2(k) $$
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{\sin k}{k} = \hat{u}(k,0) = C_1(k) + C_2(k)=2C_1(k)\implies C_1(k)=C_2(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{\sin(k)}{k}.$$
By $\mathcal{F}(g(x-c)) = e^{-ikc}\hat{g}(k)\implies \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left (\hat{g}(k)e^{tk} \right)= g(x-it)$,
\begin{align*}u(x,t) &= \mathcal{F}^{-1}(u(k,t)) = \mathcal{F}^{-1} \left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{\sin k}{k}e^{kt} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{\sin k}{k}e^{-kt} \right )\\ &= \frac{1}{2} \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left (\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \frac{\sin k}{k} e^{kt}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left (\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \frac{\sin k}{k} e^{-kt}\right) .\end{align*}
Here is the problem. For $a=1$, $\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left ( \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\sin k}{k} \right )=\chi_{[-1,1]}=f(x)$ and we have
$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left (\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \frac{\sin k}{k} e^{kt}\right)=\mathcal{F}^{-1} (\hat{f}(k)e^{kt}) = f(x-it),$$
but it's impossible since we can't do inequalities on complex numbers.

The Cauchy problem for the Laplace equation is ill-posed. Isn't the PDE to be solved the wave equation, $u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0$?
